# Key strength comparison: symmetric key vs RSA/DH key

Tags: rsa, public-key, diffie-hellman, symmetric, key-size

I came across different reputable sources quoting different equivalent symmetric key strengths for RSA/DH keys. This [NIST](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf) paper ([page 67](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf#page=67)) states the following offer corresponding security strenghts (symmetric / public):

- 80 - 1024
- 112 - 2048
- 128 - 3072

This is in line with the following paper by [RSA Labs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417095741/https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/historical/twirl-and-rsa-key-size.htm):

- 80 - 1024
- 112 - 2048

However, in "Serious Cryptography" by Jean-Philippe Aumasson author gives slightly different estimates:

- 70 - 1024
- 90 - 2048
- 128 - 4096

What could be the reason for these discrepancies?

Comment: Because each uses different estimate see [keylength](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/)

Comment: RSA labs quotes NIST as source, so it is not that strange that they would be identical. Isn't there a source (or algorithm) specified for Jean-Philippe? If not, we can ask.

Comment: I didn't find source or algorithm, sadly.